# Can I use Mathematica ML capability to translate an image of a formula?

Tags: symbolic, machine-learning

If I am given a pdf image of a mathematical symbolic formula can I translate it into Mathematica syntax using ML?

I tried using Classify, but I can only translate parts of the equation and I don't know how do to group the pieces together. Moreover, I found the training set can not have an equal sign. 
(I pasted an image because of the images in the training set).

[image: image of the training set]

produce this output:

[image]

out[201]=ω/k

Comment: Have you tried `TextRecognize`?

Comment: @Carl Lange Yes, it does not work, I think it's because a math formula is not simply text and so it had a different training.

Comment: It's quite likely that `Classify` won't work for this, unfortunately. If you have a lot of training data (I suppose it's trivial to generate) you could try to train a neural network to do it. Perhaps Classify will work if you use the right FeatureExtraction - but again, only if you have enough training data.

Comment: I wish I could do it with Mathematica.
If the appropriate training model exists in other languages, someone might package it.
[OCR of math expression](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-OCR-software-for-mathematical-symbols-and-expressions)

Comment: @Xminer, thankx for the link. Foxit has an OCR that partialy recognizes the math formulas, but is far from complete.