# convert image of mathematical form to mathematical form (OCR)

Tags: image-processing, ocr

I wish to convert images of mathematical form to mathematical form(and not the opposite).

I've found [this tool](https://mathpix.com/) which does a great job but I wondered if it's possible to enter an image directly to Wolfram Mathematica and parse the equation from the image?

[image: image of math]

will be converted to this: `Limit[(9 x - 6)/(3 x^2 - 10 x + 8) - (9 x + 24)/(4 x^2 - 9 x + 2), x -> 2]`
currently i can do it with the help of [Mathpix](https://mathpix.com/) - generate Latex or MS Word form which wolframAlpha understands, but it could have been great to do this directly from Mathmatica.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95207/1871

Comment: Related: [Trying to build a code to translate handwritten formulas using ML](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/237533/trying-to-build-a-code-to-translate-handwritten-formulas-using-ml)

Comment: Related: https://github.com/GalAster/Mathpix

Comment: I imported the packlet, but there Mathpix[]doesn't apear to be recognized by the kernel. Are you supposed to do something to the packlet object to get the function out of it? @wuyudi