# How to import equations from a pdf

Tags: import, ocr

Here is a pdf I am trying to import: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2e0z.png

Its a photo so that I can upload it here easily. I am trying to extract the formulas from this pdf but to no avail. Plaintext returns me something that is not easy to work with. Is there a way of doing it or am I doomed to do it by hand?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `am I doomed to do it by hand` I think so. This is a task that needs an AI or neural network to read the math equations from the images, and convert them to Mathematica correct syntax.  Mathematica as I understand has advanced  neural network functions. May be you could build one and train it  to read these images and convert them to Mathematica code.  But I do not think this is an easy task.  [Wolfram NeuralNetworks.html](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/NeuralNetworks.html)

Comment: @Nasser NeuralNetworks are certainly beyond me. that is unfortunate. Thank you!

Comment: They are beyond me as well. if I were you, I'll just translate them to Mathematica by hand.  it might take 30 minutes or so.

Comment: See this related question also  [can-i-use-mathematica-ml-capability-to-translate-an-image-of-a-formula](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/197754/can-i-use-mathematica-ml-capability-to-translate-an-image-of-a-formula)

Comment: Do you know how to derive these equations? It might be easier to program this in MA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](https://mathpix.com/) software can read equations from pdf and convert it to latex format.
You can paste latex equations in Mathematica. This [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2128/pasting-latex-into-a-mathematica-notebook) might help.

Comment: There is also this post on TeX SE: [State of generating $\LaTeX$ from handwriting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1443/23318).

Comment: @gwr there are few such apps. For example Maple has one that is supposed to `Enter handwritten and typeset math problems at the click of your camera using powerful AI technology`  and `Validate handwritten solutions in Maple Learn ` here is the link [MapleCalculator](https://maplesoft.com/products/MapleCalculator/index.aspx) how good they are? I do not  know as I never used any of them. I doubt they are good for any complicated math equation unless the AI is very good.  I think this is all just marketing.

Comment: @Nasser Beats me, I parse equations by reading them first and then typing them into Mma (unless they fail to simplify them first …). I had a software as early as 2008 for parsing handwritten math on a tablet, but that just worked for simple math.